# How to create range search function for created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, datepicker

I want to create a range search function for "created_at" (between created_at_from and created_at_to). 
But this function realizes only created_at_from but not created_at_to, means if created_at_from: 12.01.2019 and created_at_to: 01.01.2020 then the data after 01.01.2020 is also shown. How can I create a search function for the date range?

here is my code:
paper.rb

```
scope :search, -> (search_params) do
  return if search_params.blank?

  box_name(search_params[:box])
  .created_at_from(search_params[:created_at_from])
  .created_at_to(search_params[:created_at_to])
end
scope :box_name, -> (box) { where('box LIKE ?', "%#{box}%") if box.present? }
scope :created_at_from, -> (from) { where('? <= created_at', from) if from.present? }
scope :created_at_to, -> (to) { where('? <= created_at', to) if to.present? }
```

papers_controller.rb

```
def index
@search_params = papaer_search_params
@papers = Paper.search(@search_params).order(created_at: "DESC")
end
.
.
.
def paper_search_params
 params.fetch(:search, {}).permit(:box, :created_at_from, :created_at_to)
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(scope: :search, url: index_papers_path, method: :get, local: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :box, "Box" %>
<%= f.text_field :box, value: @search_params[:box], class: 'form-control' %>

<span id='date-form' class='input-custom'>
  <%= f.label :created_at, t('views.payment.date_from').html_safe + '：' %>
  <%= f.text_field :created_at_from, {value: @search_params[:created_at_from], :class => 'form-control datepicker', :required => false} %>　~
<%= f.text_field :created_at_to, {value: @search_params[:created_at_to], :class => 'form-control datepicker', :required => false} %>

<%= submit_tag 'Search', class: "button" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `from` and `to` queries are equal, therefore one of them doesn't work as expected. Just change them to:

```
scope :created_at_from, -> (from) { where('created_at <= ?', from) if from.present? }
scope :created_at_to,   -> (to)   { where('? <= created_at', to  ) if to.present?   }
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot, spickermann!! I only changed to 

`scope :created_at_from, -> (from) { where('? <= created_at', from) if from.present? }
scope :created_at_to, -> (to) { where('created_at <= ?', to) if to.present? }` 

and it's working.